# Manual Edit Template in Rad GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am facing one problem with telerik rad gridview, below image is my first screen, on that screen when I click on the link button `T` edit form will open but I don't know how to open  that edit template, see that exactly output in image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? what have you tried?